# INSERT into table a field value from another table along with constant

Tags: mysql

Can u guys tell INSERT into table a field value from another table along with constant input from form and days count calculation...

ive tried this but doesnt work

```
INSERT INTO keluar (nodaftar, idruang, tglkeluar, lamainap, createdby)
SELECT 
  '".$this->input->post('HiddenPasien')."',
  '".$this->input->post('asalruang')."',
  '".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."',
  TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,  tgldaftar, date('Y-m-d H:i:s')),
  '".$this->session->userdata('username')."' 
FROM pasien
```

Comment: You mean, something along the lines of `SELECT "hello",name FROM pasien`?

Comment: TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,  tgldaftar, date('Y-m-d H:i:s')),

it should be TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,  tgldaftar, '".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."'),

solved :D my mistake. thank you for coming by

Answer (score 2):

The general syntax for inserting from one table into another, and adding an additional constant or variable data at the same time is of the form:

```
INSERT INTO `table2`(Field1, Field2, Field3, ...)
   SELECT t1.Field1, t1.Field2, **Constant or VariableExpression**, ...
   FROM `table1` t1;
```

e.g.

```
INSERT INTO `table2`(Field1, Field2, Field3)
   SELECT t1.Field1, t1.Field2, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
   FROM `table1` t1;
```

SQL Fiddle [example here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bee90/1)